# How to restart spawn-fcgi which is returning Socket is already in use?

Tags: spawn-fcgi, unix-sockets

I have done `ps -aux | grep spawn-fcgi` found the pid and killed it by `kill -9 pid` but still when i rerun spawn-fcgi,it still returns `Socket is already in use`.

I am using spawn-fcgi for a `qgis` server and I need to export some env variables before I run it again.

How do i unbind `spawn-fcgi` from the socket and rerun `spawn-fcgi` successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To release the socket I needed to kill the process that was being spawned by `spawn-cgi` not kill `spawn-cgi` itself.

In my case it was the `qgis` server process.

So I did `ps aux | grep qgis`, found the process id.
Killed it by `kill 2345` where 2345 is the pid.
Ran the spawn-cgi command and it worked.